# Excel conditional formatting with multiple status updates

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I'm sure this is covered elsewhere but I guess I wasn't sure about which keywords to search.

I've got a spreadsheet with different tasks in one column.

In the next column I have the latest update from a dropdown list ("awaiting response", "awaiting approval", "on hold", "complete", and a few others).

```
row 1 | TASK 01 | ON HOLD  
row 2 | TASK 02 | AWAITING RESPONSE  
row 3 | TASK 03 | ON HOLD  
row 4 | TASK 02 | AWAITING APPROVAL  
row 5 | TASK 01 | AWAITING APPROVAL  
row 6 | TASK 03 | AWAITING APPROVAL  
row 7 | TASK 02 | COMPLETE
```

I have conditional formatting in place so that the "TASK __" cells are red when the status in column 2 states anything but complete. In this case, the task cell in row 7 would no longer be red.  However, the task 02 cells in rows 2 and 4 remain red.

How can I use conditional formatting to make ALL of the "TASK 02" cells in column 1 change from red to no color fill when I mark TASK 02 as completed in row 7?

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,"COMPLETE")>0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your current conditional formatting rule is along the lines of

```
=$B1<>"Complete"
```

change it to

```
=AND($B1<>"Complete",COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,"COMPLETE")=0)
```

That will only apply the format if none of the tasks with the current row's ID are complete.

Edit: as pointed out in a comment, the first test in the AND() is now obsolete, so the formula is just

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,"COMPLETE")=0
```

(but not `>0` as suggested in the comment to the question).

[image]

Comment: as to my comment to the question.  I understood it that the OP had colored the cells red and took the red out when complete was filled in.  So the reverse. Which why the ">0" .  I was waiting on the OP to respond before correcting.

Comment: Sorry, I've been AWOL for a few days.  Yes, I'd like to have the column A cells red for each specific task until that task is complete.  When a task is complete, all cells from the same task would be cleared (no longer red).  Thanks to all for assistance with this.

Comment: Yes. That's what my suggestion does. It shows in the screenshot. Task 2 is marked complete in row 7 and now all Task 2 related rows are no longer red.